Are 4-vectors really vectors in general relativity?
After watching this video about geodesics, I am now confused about where 4-vectors fit in general relativity. I already checked this question but it didn't help much. I am still learning the formalities of differential geometry. Let me know if I misunderstood anything.
Let $M$ be a 4D spacetime manifold and $(U,\phi)$ be one of its coordinate charts where $U\subseteq M$ is an open patch of the manifold. A trajectory of an apple in $U$ is parametrized by a smooth map $\lambda:\mathbb R\to U$.
I think $x^\alpha(\tau)=\phi(\lambda(\tau))=(cx^0(\tau),x^1(\tau),x^2(\tau),x^3(\tau))$ is what one calls "position 4-vector" but it is a point, not a vector, despite its name.
A "velocity 4-vector" seems to be defined as $u^\alpha=\frac{dx^\alpha}{d\tau}=(c\frac{dx^0}{d\tau}, \frac{dx^1}{d\tau}, \frac{dx^2}{d\tau}, \frac{dx^3}{d\tau})$. I am not sure if it is a point or vector.
Similarly, a "acceleration 4-vector" is defined as $a^\alpha=\frac{du^\alpha}{d\tau}=(c\frac{d^2x^0}{d\tau^2}, \frac{d^2x^1}{d\tau^2}, \frac{d^2x^2}{d\tau^2}, \frac{d^2x^3}{d\tau^2})$.
Let $\{\vec{e}_0, \vec{e}_1, \vec{e}_2, \vec{e}_3\}$ be coordinate basis vectors for the tangent space $T_{\lambda(\tau)}M$.
In the linked video, he defines the "velocity vector" (I thought it refers to "velocity 4-vector") of the apple as $\vec{u}^\alpha=u^\alpha\vec{e}_\alpha$. He defined the "acceleration vector" to be
$$
\begin{align*}
\vec{a}^\alpha &= \frac{d\vec{u}^\alpha}{d\tau} \\
&= \frac{du^\alpha}{d\tau}\vec{e}_\alpha+u^\alpha\frac{d\vec{e}_\alpha}{d\tau} \\
&= \frac{du^\alpha}{d\tau}\vec{e}_\alpha+u^\alpha\left(\left(\frac{d\vec{e}_\alpha}{d\tau}\cdot\vec{e}_\gamma\right)\vec{e}_\gamma\right) \\
&= \frac{du^\alpha}{d\tau}\vec{e}_\alpha+u^\alpha\left(\left(\frac{d\vec{e}_\alpha}{dx^\beta}\frac{dx^\beta}{d\tau}\cdot\vec{e}_\gamma\right)\vec{e}_\gamma\right) \\
&= \frac{du^\alpha}{d\tau}\vec{e}_\alpha+u^\alpha\left(\left(\frac{d\vec{e}_\alpha}{dx^\beta}\cdot\vec{e}_\gamma\right)u^\beta\vec{e}_\gamma\right) \\
&= \frac{du^\alpha}{d\tau}\vec{e}_\alpha+\Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\nu} u^\mu u^\nu\vec{e}_\alpha \\
&= \left(a^\alpha+\Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\nu} u^\mu u^\nu\right)\vec{e}_\alpha
\end{align*}
$$
It was surprising to me because I thought "acceleration 4-vector" $a^\alpha$ can be written as $\vec{a}^\alpha=a^\alpha\vec{e}_\alpha$ but it seems to be false.
I am struggling to see how 4-vectors $u^\alpha$ and $a^\alpha$ fits in the picture. It seems like they are not vectors, contrary to my expectations. Are they points on the manifold?

Points live on the manifold (i.e. spacetime), vectors on the tangent space. The 4-velocity is a legit vector (morally, differentiation takes you to the tangent space). This may also help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/489827/226902

@user366875 I think you need to clarify in your question why do you think it is not considered a true vector

@OfekGillon I need to know the precise definition of 4-vectors to be sure. It seems to me that 4-velocity and 4-acceleration are nothing but proper time derivatives of 4-position components.

@user366875 from the question: "...is what one calls "position 4-vector" but it is a point, not a vector, despite its name". It is not clear what you meant when you wrote it: on what basis are you making this distinction between a point and a vector?

@OfekGillon a point on a manifold is not necessarily a vector

@user366875 , Agreed, if you first give a definition: what is a vector, and why is a point on a manifold ($M\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n , n\geq 3$) not a vector?

@OfekGillon  A vector is an element of a tangent space. I think a point on a manifold cannot be a vector… point and vector are two different concepts

@user366875 Well $\mathbb{R^4}$ is the tangent space for the manifold $\mathbb{R^4}$, so points in that space can be considered vectors by your definition

@OfekGillon What is your point, exactly? $\mathbb{R}^4$ is not "the" tangent space for the "manifold" $\mathbb{R}^4$. Plus, you are confusing the vector space $\mathbb{R}^4$ with a manifold $(\mathbb{R}^4,g)$. A tangent space is tangent to a point in a manifold. Vector fields are sections of the tangent bundle, vectors are restrictions of a section to a point of the manifold, that's all.

Related: Does spacetime position not form a four-vector?

Your confusion here probably stems from the lack of distinction between "a vector", and "components of a vector".

A vector $\vec{a}$ is a geometric object - and a 4 vector is just a 4 dimensional vector together with a transformation law.
The components of a vector $a^\alpha$ are the numbers which act as "weights" to express our vector as a sum of basis vectors, which are a set of vectors denoted: $ \vec{e}_\alpha$.  The values of these components depends on the choice of basis.


Where you have written objects with the arrow on top, e.g. $\vec{a}^\alpha $,  you are referring to the geometric vector. The superscript alpha is misleading here - it implies you are talking about the components when you are really trying to talk about the vector as a whole, so I will drop it going forwards.
Any vector, e.g. $\vec{u} $ can be expressed as a sum of basis vectors, so using summation convention, we could write:  $\vec{u} =u^\alpha \vec{e}_\alpha $
The numbers $u^\alpha$ are the vector components and $\vec{u} $ is the vector.
When we take a derivative of such an object, we can apply product rule to it:
$\frac{d}{d\tau}  { \vec{u} } = \frac{d}{d\tau}  ({ u^\alpha \vec{e}_\alpha }) = \frac{d}{d\tau}  { (u^\alpha)} \vec{e}_\alpha  +  u^\alpha \frac{d}{d\tau}  { \vec{e}_\alpha }$
The Christoffel symbols $\Gamma$ enter the picture as derivatives of the basis vectors. This is important in curved spacetime or in curved coordinates, where the basis vectors are non-constant: Each point has a different basis set, so if we are following a particle along its world line, the basis would change and the basis vectors would have non-vanishing derivatives with respect to proper time.
From this point on, I hope the confusion vanishes.

Another possible source of confusion is in general relativity, these 4-vectors are only defined "at a point in spacetime" - i.e. they are elements of the tangent space to a specific point in spacetime (which is a Lorentzian Manifold).
4-vectors at different points in spacetime are not directly comparable and you have to compare them by finding a path between them integrating quantities along such a path.
4-vectors also cannot be used to describe positions in spacetime since in GR spacetime is a manifold not a vector space. You cannot add points on a meaningful way, analogous to how you cannot add GPS coordinates together to get a meaningful quantity.

If you think of a point as a vector to the point from a reference point (which will look exactly like the point itself), then you can easily add them (and, even more usefully, subtract them).

Thank you. It seems like a tuple $(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)$ can ambiguously interpreted as either (i) a point in spacetime or (ii) components of a geometric vector $\vec{x}$.

So in GR, acceleration 4-vector is $\vec{a}=\left(a^\alpha+\Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\nu} u^\mu u^\nu\right)\vec{e}\alpha$. In flat spacetime, it becomes $\vec{a}=a^\alpha\vec{e}\alpha$. This is the acceleration 4-vector I am familiar with.

In flat spacetime, Γ =0, and so: $ \vec{a}^\alpha = \frac{du^\alpha}{d\tau}\vec{e}_\alpha $ , which likely the definition you are familiar with.

What’s the transformation law for 4-vectors in GR?

@KierD well, let’s be clear: having flat spacetime does not imply $\Gamma=0$. In a flat spacetime there exist coordinates in which $\Gamma=0$, but there are certainly many others where it is not.
